# Getting the active_model_serializer for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2, active-model-serializers

I am trying to send multiple different objects over a generic request
- more specificly - I have different types of users, with different model, all might be return when creating a new session.
looking at rail casts #409 - ryan calls model.active_model_serializers.new - this does not work for me.
is there any other way to get the seriailzer without knowing what model am I serializing?

I am using rails 4.2 and active_model_serializers 0.9.3

Answer (score 0):

use active_model_serializers gem

```
render :json => object, :serializer => ApiUser
```

or you have an array of object than

```
render :json => objects, :each_serializer => ApiUser
```

create a file api_user.rb in serializers folder